# Match Sublime es6 syntax highlighting

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to get syntax highlighting similar?

- Match the function name colors
- Colorize object (exports)

[image]

Comment: Do you have the `babel` package for Sublime ?

Answer (score 1):

This extension helped me: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dzannotti.vscode-babel-coloring

Thanks to @naomik for the hint.